# SQL: I want to insert value into a table in a loop, how to do it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, for-loop

```
INSERT INTO [AAAA_DEV].[XXXX].[SalesStageRoleText]
           ([SubRolesId]
           ,[SalesStageID]
           ,[DisplayNameTextID]
           ,[CreateTstamp]
           ,[CreateUserID]
           ,[LastUpdateProcessName]
           ,[LastUpdateTstamp]
           ,[LastUpdateUserID])
     VALUES
           (
           1
           ,@salesstageID
           ,'Contract_SalesStage_Merged'
           ,GETDATE()
           ,'Temp'
           ,'Temp'
           ,GETDATE()
           ,'Temp'
           )
END
```

`SubRolesId` is primary key.
`SalesStageID` value is 1 to 20.
Now i want to insert value into `[XXXX].[SalesStageRoleText]` table using above query.

But how will i write a for loop to insert 20 values while only `SalesStageID` vary from 1 to 20?

Comment: Although there are better ways, the specific answer to the question in your title is `while`:  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi_v-yE7bXKAhVC5CYKHd5LDvkQFgghMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fms178642.aspx&usg=AFQjCNGgfmQAz5cC3QR2NFJ7G_YwSjMXzQ&sig2=HcqSP3mwwC6EKaITO0qbEQ&bvm=bv.112064104,d.cWw.

Comment: Your question is not clear. post desired input and output. And tag to dbms u're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'While loop' can be a solution to iterate, but I would avoid any iteration within t-sql unless it is really necessary.

```
DECLARE @salesstageID INT=1
   WHILE @salesstageID<=20
   BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [AAAA_DEV].[XXXX].[SalesStageRoleText]
            ([SubRolesId]
            ,[SalesStageID]
            ,[DisplayNameTextID]
            ,[CreateTstamp]
            ,[CreateUserID]
            ,[LastUpdateProcessName]
            ,[LastUpdateTstamp]
            ,[LastUpdateUserID])
        VALUES
            (
            1
            ,@salesstageID
            ,'Contract_SalesStage_Merged'
            ,GETDATE()
            ,'Temp'
            ,'Temp'
            ,GETDATE()
            ,'Temp'
            )
        END
        SET @salesstageID=@salesstageID+1
   END
```

Comment: @salesstageID = @salesstageID+ 1

Comment: For this I am getting Incorrect syntax near '@salesstageID'. error

Comment: You should add this SET @salesstageID=@salesstageID+1